# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given (Error)

Tags: php, mysqli

This is the code:

```
$dbConn = mysqli_connect ($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die ('MySQL connect failed. ' . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($dbName) or die('Cannot select database. ' . mysqli_error());
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLFkP.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Share the errors or exceptions you might be getting.

Answer (score 1):

change `mysqli_select_db($dbName)` to `mysqli_select_db($dbConn,$dbName)`

please go through this - [w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) for more info on using mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide two parameters to [mysqli_select_db()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) - a link identifier returned by `mysqli_connect()` and the database name:

```
$dbConn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass);
mysqli_select_db($dbConn, $dbName);
```

If you need to perform a query on the database, use [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
$sql = ' ... SQL statement ...';
mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql);
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\courier-management-system-freeproject24.com\courier\database.php on line 15

Comment: @cdjay Where is this `mysqli_query()` call? Use `mysqli_query ($dbConn, ' ... Your statement ...')` if you need to execute SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's cause you just provide 1 parameter, when expect 2 parameter.

You need to provide second parameters to mysqli_select_db().

> First parameter is `your connection` in this case `$dbConn`
>
> And second is your `database name`

change this `mysqli_select_db($dbName)` to this `mysqli_select_db($dbConn,$dbName)`

For detail you can check [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp)